# How to programmatically cancel a swipe to delete in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has a swipe to delete action using:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

This works perfectly fine, however there are some situation where the delete should not happen, in this situation when swiping to delete and pressing the delete button the button doesn't disappear but stays there as if nothing is happening.

It seems to me the delete button only collapses when the row is removed from the table (or its backing store).

Is there a way to tell the view to cancel the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the logic for determining if the row is eligible for editing to

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` (from `UITableViewDataSource`)

Of course this prevents all editing of the cell not just deleting, this may not be the way to go if you want to allow editing but not deleting.

Comment: If I wasn't currently targeting iOS 10 I could probably use: `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)`